# Use TestFlight for internal testing

Tags: ios, testing, continuous-integration, app-store-connect, testflight

In my company we are developing an iOS app, as we are a lot of developers working on many features we would like to deploy some work in progress version of our app to our QA/PO so then can continuously test it.

Before we were using App Distribution from Firebase but we reached the number of devices registered in the certificates.
So we would like to move to TestFlight, but it's not possible to deploy build with custom name, for example a build named "Feature-A".
Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not deploy build with custom name for every release. Deploy builds should have same app name and bundle identifier should be same which is registered on apple developer account.if it is mismatched then user getting error while uploading app build on developer account.

For every build you should mention description of which feature or module is implemented and for which part testing build is release on TestFlight.